# Generate a pre signed S3 URL using the Javascript AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to allow access to assets from a presigned URL but I am unsure of how to do this.  From [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) I can see I need the following:

> ```
> Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;
>
> Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );
>
> StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
>   Content-MD5 + "\n" +
>   Content-Type + "\n" +
>   Date + "\n" +
>   CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
>   CanonicalizedResource;
>
> CanonicalizedResource = [ "/" + Bucket ] +
>   <HTTP-Request-URI, from the protocol name up to the query string> +
>   [ subresource, if present. For example "?acl", "?location", "?logging", or "?torrent"];
>
> CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = <described below>
> ```

I know how to find the `AWSAccessKeyId` and the `YourSecretAccessKeyID` but how do I encode it using `HMAC-SHA1` to form the final signature?

Comment: This pseudocode is unrelated to generating signed URLs with the Javascript SDK.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, I thought this is how you generate it

Comment: It seems you can generate it like so:

`s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
      console.log("The URL is", url);
    });`

but that is to download the file, I just need to be able to display it in a browser

Comment: That will also work for displaying the file, if you uploaded it to S3 with the correct content type.  Check that in the metadata of the object, in the S3 console.

Comment: What would I be looking for? Mine says "content/type application/octet-stream" and thats it

Answer (score 5):

I was able to generate a presigned URL for fetching files like according to [this Amazon S3 node example page](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html):

```
declare var AWS:any;

AWS.config.accessKeyId = "key_goes_here";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "secret_key_goes_here";
AWS.config.region = "region_goes_here";

params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket_name_goes_here',
    Key:  'path_to_file_goes_here'
}

s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) { 
    // Do some sort of processing with url
});
```